# Somar números respeitando formatação R$ 00,00

Tags: javascript, html

Boa tarde

Estou tentando representar uma soma que o valor de saída esteja na formatação abaixo:

> **R$ 00,00**

Porém estou com dificuldades com os números das casas decimais,

em vez do número ficar **R$ 15,10** ele fica na formatação **R$ 15,1**

Podem me ajudar?

Segue abaixo o andamento do codigo:

```html
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function id( el ){
        return document.getElementById( el );
}
function getMoney( el ){
        var money = id( el ).value.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'');
        return parseFloat( money );
}
function soma()
{
        var total = (getMoney('campo1')+getMoney('campo2')+getMoney('campo3'))/100;

                    id('campo4').value = ('R$'+total).toString().replace('.', ',');

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
        <form action="" method="">
                <input name="campo1" id="campo1" value="10,00" /><br />
                <input name="campo2" id="campo2" value="4,10" /><br />
                <input name="campo3" id="campo3" value="1,00" /><br />
                <input name="campo4" readonly="readonly" id="campo4" /><br />
                <input type="button" onclick="soma()" value="Soma de Valores" />
        </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Olá
Talvez este trecho lhe ajude:

```js
parseFloat(10.4).toFixed("2").replace(".", ",").replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "$1.")
```

Ficaria assim:

```html
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function id( el ){
        return document.getElementById( el );
}
function getMoney( el ){
        var money = id( el ).value.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'');
        return parseFloat( money );
}
function soma()
{
        var total = (getMoney('campo1')+getMoney('campo2')+getMoney('campo3'))/100;

                    id('campo4').value = ('R$'+parseFloat(total).toFixed("2").replace(".", ",").replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "$1."));

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
        <form action="" method="">
                <input name="campo1" id="campo1" value="10,00" /><br />
                <input name="campo2" id="campo2" value="4,10" /><br />
                <input name="campo3" id="campo3" value="1,00" /><br />
                <input name="campo4" readonly="readonly" id="campo4" /><br />
                <input type="button" onclick="soma()" value="Soma de Valores" />
        </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Basta você chamar o [toFixed(2)](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tofixed.asp) na exibição.

Dessa forma o seu cálculo é feito independente das casas decimais e exibido de forma arredondada com quantas casas você desejar.

Answer (score 1):

Incluí mais uma instrução: `total = total.toFixed(2);`

Veja mais sobe toFixed aqui: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed

Veja como fica:

```html
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function id( el ){
        return document.getElementById( el );
}
function getMoney( el ){
        var money = id( el ).value.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'');
        return parseFloat( money );
}
function soma()
{
        var total = (getMoney('campo1')+getMoney('campo2')+getMoney('campo3'))/100;
        total = total.toFixed(2);

                    id('campo4').value = ('R$'+total).toString().replace('.', ',');

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
        <form action="" method="">
                <input name="campo1" id="campo1" value="10,00" /><br />
                <input name="campo2" id="campo2" value="4,10" /><br />
                <input name="campo3" id="campo3" value="1,00" /><br />
                <input name="campo4" readonly="readonly" id="campo4" /><br />
                <input type="button" onclick="soma()" value="Soma de Valores" />
        </form>
</body>
</html>
```